# ESLint extend error : Failing to load config

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, eslint-config-airbnb

- Node version: v16.13.1
- npm version: v8.1.2
- Local ESLint version: Not found
- Global ESLint version: Not found
- Operating System: linux 5.13.0-28-generic

My project structure :

```
helloworld
  src
    UI
      debug.js
    public
      node_modules
        eslint
        eslint-config-airbnb-base
        eslint-plugin-import
  .eslintrc.json
  package.json
  debug.js
  .yarnrc
```

.yarnrc :

```
--*.modules-folder "./src/public/node_modules"
```

.eslintrc.json :

```
{
    "root": true,
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "airbnb-base"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest"
    },
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

When I run the linter in terminal using `src/public/node_modules/.bin/eslint debug.js` OR `src/public/node_modules/.bin/eslint src/ui/debug.js` it's throwing the below error.

> Oops! Something went wrong! :(
>
> ESLint: 8.8.0
>
> ESLint couldn't find the config "airbnb-base" to extend from. Please
> check that the name of the config is correct.
>
> The config "airbnb-base" was referenced from the config file in
> "/projects/linter/helloworld/.eslintrc.json".

BUT - if I move the `.eslintrc.json` & `debug.js` to `/src/public` and run `src/public/node_modules/.bin/eslint src/public/debug.js`, the file will be linted successfully.

How could I point the eslint to refer the config in `src/public/node_modules/` so it would lint the `debug.js` in root as well as in `/src/ui/` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Having `eslintrc.json` in the project root shouldn't be a problem.

Could you please post the content of `package.json`?

Meanwhile, here are some suggestions for what could be conflicting:

- If `eslint-config-airbnb-base` isn't in `package.json`, try to install it:

```
yarn add --dev eslint-config-airbnb-base
```

- If ESLint was installed globally, try to remove it and install it locally instead:

```
yarn global remove eslint
yarn add --dev eslint
```

Comment: `package.json` does have all the relevant packages. also the `eslint-config-airbnb-base` is installed as a dev dependency. Further I don't have ESLint installed globally.